# How Facebook ad loads on Facebook once the Facebook pixel drops on the browser

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-pixel

I'am trying to load the ad on Facebook based on the pixel, I have created the Custom Audience rule  {"and":[{"event":{"eq":"Audience"}},{"or":[{"segmentName":{"i_contains":"Hi"}}]}]} of type website and linked product catalogue and it has total 12 product in a selected product set and also catalogue has associated Pixel.

**In this case how Facebook loads the ad?? if we drops the pixel once in the browser is Facebook loads the ad Immediately?? or also it has to pass the bidding process to load the ad on Facebook??**

**More info regarding Audience**

> {
>    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
>    "name": "jvxblr-2 Audience",
>    "rule": "{"and":[{"event":{"eq":"Audience"}},{"or":[{"segmentName":{"i_contains":"jvxblr-2"}}]}]}",
>    "retention_days": 30,
>    "data_source": {
>      "type": "EVENT_BASED",
>      "sub_type": "WEB_PIXEL_HITS",
>      "creation_params": "{"prefill":"true"}"
>    },
>    "delivery_status": {
>      "code": 300,
>      "description": "Audiences must include at least 20 people to be used >for ads."
>    },
>    "pixel_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
>    "external_event_source": {
>      "id": "xxxxxxxxx"
>   },
>    "subtype": "WEBSITE"
>   }

Answer (score 0):

Creating this audience rule allows Facebook to include website visitors into your audience. Once your audience is populated, you'll need to create an Ad Campaign using [Ads Manager](https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/), [Power Editor](http://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/powereditor) or the Ads Management API. Ad Set(s) in your campaign can reference the audience you've created for targeting. Your Ad will also include your goals and bidding information that the Facebook Ad Delivery System will take into account in delivering your targeted ad.

Comment: Jeff S, Thanks for reply, I have followed exactly same steps what you have mentioned, but am wondering that once pixel drops on browser, how actually ad loads on Facebook networks.

Comment: The pixel fire uses cookies to match to a Facebook identity. Facebook marks that person as in the audience and eligible to receive the ad you've configured. When the person logs in, all ads they're eligible to see compete for the available ad slots.